# Disable Windows 8 auto ending programs

Tags: windows, windows-8, process, tasks

I often lose my unsaved work because of Windows 8's stupid feature that ends unresponsive programs once the dialog box, "This program is not responding" appears. Are there any options I can disable it?

Comment: 1) Save your work, and save often. 2) You should figure out why your programs quit responding - that's the real issue.

Comment: 1) I do save my work frequently, but sometimes we get engrossed in our work and forget to save. 2) How can I find out? I'm not a programmer and I don't know how to use a debugger. Windows 8 just end the unresponsive programs forcefully and I can do nothing about it, and it doesn't happen in Windows 7.

Comment: @MegaRodeon - The simplest way is to determine what causes the crash of a given application.  Once you do that you come here, describe the problem, and we provide a solution.  This behavior of crashing an application that has crashed isn't a new feature in Windows and not limited to Windows 8.

Comment: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-auto-termination-of-applications-that-block-windows-8-shutdown/

Comment: @Ramhound I think determining what causes Windows is *quite* useless, because I never did any significant changes to Windows 7 and 8, so Windows 8 starts crashing programs. But I think I should give it a shot though, of figuring out what's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MegaRodeon - All I know is that an application that is working will not crash.  So if the application is crashing some instruction its doing is causing it to crash itself.

Comment: @Ramhound - Of course a working application won't crash itself and I don't see there's any problem with the instructions my programs are handling. Only when the program is unresponsive for a certain time and I try to click it, it crashes once the dialog box appears. And as I've said, it doesn't happen in Windows 7 so I'm thinking it could be changes made to either registry or Local Group Policies in Windows 8.